# What are the default compilerOptions in a TypeScript tsconfig file?

Tags: typescript

On the TypeScript page that describes the tsconfig.json file, it says,

> The "compilerOptions" property can be omitted, in which case the compiler’s defaults are used. See our full list of supported Compiler Options.

However, I cannot find these defaults anywhere.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, or, if you know, post them here?

Alternatively, I thought of outputting the compilerOptions to console somehow, but I don't know how to do that.

Edit: So, I just realized something that I think helps answer this question.  I think the boolean options all default to false, which might explain why the default values for those aren't mentioned.  If that's the case, then it leaves the following options without defaults documented (but I have to admit, these all seem like they have obvious defaults):

--charset

--locale

--newLine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, I cannot find these defaults anywhere

The `compilerOptions` has its own page and that mentions some defaults : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Compiler%20Options.md

For your question

- `charset`: utf8. You don't need to mess with this in most cases
- `locale` : `en-us`. I don't even know how well the others are supported.
- `newLine` : Uses the `os` default. Unless you specify explicitly (CR or CRLF)

Comment: The `Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook` GitHub repo is archived. [Up-to-date GitHub link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/blob/v2/packages/documentation/copy/en/project-config/Compiler%20Options.md) + [same page on typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).